# Using has_many "both" in neo4j.rb

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I'm looking for a way to set up a relationship between `User`s where you can use `in`, `out`, and `both` all at the same time in Neo4j.rb.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class User
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  has_many :both, :friends, type: :connection, model_class: User
  has_many :out, :following, type: :connection, model_class: User
  has_many :in, :followers, type: :connection, model_class: User
end
```

The following works:

```
me = User.create
you = User.create

me.followers << you
me.followers.to_a
#=> [you]

you.following.to_a
#=> [me]
```

The opposite of above works as well. But this doesn't seem to work:

```
me.friends << you
you.following.to_a
#=> []
```

Or:

```
me.followers.to_a
#=> []
```

However, this does:

```
me.following.to_a
#=> [you]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  Neo4j doesn't allow you to create relationships which don't have a direction.  Thus, the `both` association type is only for querying (that is, when querying it specifies the relationship, but not the direction to/from the node).

Since Neo4j relationships always have a direction, when you create relationships with a `both` association it creates them as `out` relationships.  See this section in the docs:

https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-v3-Declared-Relationships#all-has_manyhas_one-method-calls-begin-with-declaration-of-direction

Thinking about it now, I'm wondering if perhaps Neo4j.rb shouldn't let you create relationships using `both` associations.  What do you think?  I'll create a Github issue as well

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Digging into it a little bit deeper, it's a feature that I don't think that I would need either way.

Comment: Great ;)  The other thing I forgot to mention: You should get into the habit of using strings for `model_class` like this: , `model_class: 'User'`